# rails can not connect to the globale database server even host name and database are given

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in my rail application,
in database.yml file I  given all the fields such as host, database , username, password,and etc.. but it did not connect to the server(here am trying to connect with global database )

and it gives an error as" Access denied for user 'myappdemo'@'142.25.12.1' (using password: yes)"

when I try to connect my local host it is connected incase of host is given as "127.0.0.1"
ie host is an IP address.. but not with "localhost"

Comment: What kind of database are you using? Some databases do discriminate access with/without passsword based on IPs or hosts (different)

Comment: Can you connect to the global server via terminal? First ensure that your credentials are correct and the database server is configured to accept remote requests.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to the localhost here, as the error message seems to indicate you are connection to some other ip ? `142.25.12.1`